# NoReverseMatch at "/result"

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I am trying to add a like system to my blog posts in my blog app. I was watching a tutorial on how to add a like button, however it was part of a course so has different variables and models for example. When I try and load my 'detail_post' url I get the following error:

Here is my error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /blog/d-test-post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\myblogsite\blog\views.py", line 62, in detail_blog_view
    return render(request, 'detail_blog.html', {'blog_post': blog_post,
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'like' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/like$']
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.conf import settings
from account.models import Account


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    file_path = 'blog/media/posts/{author_id}/{title}-{filename}'.format(
    author_id=str(instance.author_id), title=str(instance.title), filename=filename
    )
    return file_path

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=False, blank=False)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date published")
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="date updated")
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

@receiver(post_delete, sender=BlogPost)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.image.delete(False)

def pre_save_blog_post_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.author.username + "-" + instance.title)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_blog_post_reciever, sender=BlogPost)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "myapp_comment"
```

Here is my views.py, I am only including my like post view because I think the rest is irreverent for my problem :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import BlogPost
from blog.forms import CreateBlogPostForm, UpdateBlogPostForm, CommentForm
from account.models import Account
from operator import attrgetter
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy

def like_view(request, slug):
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    blog_post.likes.add(request.Account.author)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', args=[str(slug)]))
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import BlogPost, Comment

class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
            'image'

        ]

class UpdateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'image']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        blog_post = self.instance
        blog_post.title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        blog_post.body = self.cleaned_data['body']

        if self.cleaned_data['image']:
            blog_post.image = self.cleaned_data['image']

        if commit:
            blog_post.save()
        return blog_post



class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

Here is my html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}


<style type="text/css">
    .card{
        max-width: 700px;
    }
    .card-body{
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Blog Post -->
        <div class="card m-auto">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{blog_post.image.url}}">
            <div class="card-body mt-2 mb-2">
              <h2 class="card-title">{{blog_post.title}}</h2>
              <p class="card-text">{{blog_post.body|safe}}</p>
              {% if blog_post.author == request.user %}
                <a href="{% url 'blog:edit' slug=blog_post.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
              Updated on {{blog_post.date_updated}} by {{blog_post.author}}
                <br/><br/>
                <hr>
                <br/>
                <form action="{% url 'blog:like' post.slug %}"
                method="POST">
                <button type="submit", name=post_id, value="{{ blog_post.slug }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            <a class="card-text", href="{% url 'blog:comment' blog_post.slug %}">Comments</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Finally here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import (
    create_blog_view,
    detail_blog_view,
    top_profiles_view,
    edit_blog_view,
    detail_comment_view,
    like_view

)

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug>/like', like_view, name="like"),
    path('<slug>/comments', detail_comment_view, name='comment' ),
    path('create-post/', create_blog_view, name="create_post"),
    path('top3/', top_profiles_view, name='top3'),
    path('<slug>/', detail_blog_view, name="detail"),
    path('<slug>/edit', edit_blog_view, name="edit")
 ]
```

Here is my detail_blog_view:

```
def detail_blog_view(request, slug):
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    comments = blog_post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = blog_post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'detail_blog.html', {'blog_post': blog_post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

I'm running into quite a lot of errors.

Comment: You don't have any url patterns that match `/result`.

Comment: Also, the error traceback says the problem is in `detail_blog_view()`, which you didn't show us.

Comment: @JohnGordon i have just updated my post with the detail_blog_view included.